# Magento 1.9: SOAP API Inventory Item Update not updating the all data

Tags: magento-1.9, soap-api-v1

I am trying to update the Stock data,Using SOAP V1, but many values are not updating.

```
$stock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($product);
$stockItemData = array(
    'qty' => $qty,
    'is_in_stock' => $product->getIsInStock(),
    'manage_stock' => $stock->getManageStock(),
    'use_config_manage_stock' => $stock->getUseConfigManageStock(),
    'min_qty' => $stock->getMinQty(),//not updated
    'use_config_min_qty' => $stock->getUseConfigMinQty(),//not updated
    'min_sale_qty' => $stock->getMinSaleQty(),//not updated
    'use_config_min_sale_qty' => $stock->getUseConfigMinSaleQty(),//not updated
    'max_sale_qty' => $stock->getMaxSaleQty(),//not updated
    'use_config_max_sale_qty' => $stock->getUseConfigMaxSaleQty(),//not updated
    'is_qty_decimal' => $stock->getIsQtyDecimal(),//not updated
    'backorders' => $stock->getBackorders(),//not updated
    'use_config_backorders' => $stock->getUseConfigBackorders(),//not updated
    'notify_stock_qty' => $stock->getNotifyStockQty(),//not updated
    'use_config_notify_stock_qty' => $stock->getUseConfigNotifyStockQty(),//not updated
    'stock_status_changed_auto' => $stock->getStockStatusChangedAuto(),//not updated
    'use_config_qty_increments' => $stock->getUseConfigQtyIncrements(),//not updated
    'qty_increments' => $stock->getQtyIncrements(),//not updated
    'use_config_enable_qty_inc' => $stock->getUseConfigEnableQtyInc(),
    'enable_qty_increments' => $stock->getEnableQtyIncrements(),//not updated
    'is_decimal_divided' => $stock->getIsDecimalDivided(),//not updated
    'type_id' => $stock->getTypeId(),
    'stock_status_changed_automatically' => $stock->getStockStatusChangedAutomatically(),//not updated
    'use_config_enable_qty_increments' => $stock->getUseConfigEnableQtyIncrements()
);
$proxy->call($sessionId, 'product_stock.update', array($product->getId(), $stockItemData));
```

I have checked, all  the passed values, and its correct,and even tried to pass static value to test, but not worked.
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by running this way

```
$soapMulticalls = array();
$stock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($product);
$arrProductsExists = $proxy->call($sessionId, 'catalog_product.list');
$soapMulticallDataItem = array(
    'catalog_product.update',
    array(
        $product->getSku(),
        array(
            'stock_data' => array(
            'qty' => $qty,
            'is_in_stock' => $product->getIsInStock(),
            'manage_stock' => $stock->getManageStock(),
            'use_config_manage_stock' => $stock->getUseConfigManageStock(),
            'min_qty' => $stock->getMinQty(),
            'use_config_min_qty' => $stock->getUseConfigMinQty(),
            'min_sale_qty' => $stock->getMinSaleQty(),
            'use_config_min_sale_qty' => $stock->getUseConfigMinSaleQty(),
            'max_sale_qty' => $stock->getMaxSaleQty(),
            'use_config_max_sale_qty' => $stock->getUseConfigMaxSaleQty(),
            'is_qty_decimal' => $stock->getIsQtyDecimal(),
            'backorders' => $stock->getBackorders(),
            'use_config_backorders' => $stock->getUseConfigBackorders(),
            'notify_stock_qty' => $stock->getNotifyStockQty(),
            'use_config_notify_stock_qty' => $stock->getUseConfigNotifyStockQty(),
            'stock_status_changed_auto' => $stock->getStockStatusChangedAuto(),
            'use_config_qty_increments' => $stock->getUseConfigQtyIncrements(),
            'qty_increments' => $stock->getQtyIncrements(),
            'use_config_enable_qty_inc' => $stock->getUseConfigEnableQtyInc(),
            'enable_qty_increments' => $stock->getEnableQtyIncrements(),
            'is_decimal_divided' => $stock->getIsDecimalDivided(),
            'type_id' => $stock->getTypeId(),
            'stock_status_changed_automatically' => $stock->getStockStatusChangedAutomatically(),
            'use_config_enable_qty_increments' => $stock->getUseConfigEnableQtyIncrements()
            )
        )
    )
);
array_push($soapMulticalls, $soapMulticallDataItem);
if (count($soapMulticalls) > 0) {
    $proxy->multiCall($sessionId, $soapMulticalls);
}
```

And its working fine ;)